# Как запустить cuda profiler?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

При запуске профайлера выдает ошибку:

> ======== Profiling all processes launched by user "Иван"
>   ==9684== NVPROF is profiling process 9684, command: sh_dis  3000
>   ==9684== Error: Cannot create profiling file: C:\Users\Иван\nvvp_workspace.metadata.plugins\com.nvidia.viper\launch\0\api_9684.log

Из-за чего это может быть, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Может прав нет, может софт кривой...

Comment: Софт ставил с оф сайта nvidia, а как права организовать?